# c macro that knows the programs output file name

Tags: c, macros

Is there a way to conditionally including
 a section of code depending on the build output
 filename with GCC ( specifically mingw / codeblocks )

For example:

I have 2 profile files:

project 1 compiles to foo.exe 
 project 2 compiles to bar.exe

both project include a file called myheaders.h

inside myheaders.h , there is information about
 the program,

```
 #define APP_TITLE                     "my project"
 #define APP_VERSION                    0,0,0,1
 #define APP_VERSION_STR               "0,0,0,1"
```

My question: is the following possible

```
          #if __OUTPUT__ =="foo.exe"
          #define APP_TITLE                     "my project"
          #define APP_VERSION                    0,0,0,1
          #define APP_VERSION_STR               "0,0,0,1"
          #endif

          #if __OUTPUT__ =="bar.exe"
          #define APP_TITLE                     "side project"
          #define APP_VERSION                    0,0,2,2
          #define APP_VERSION_STR               "0,0,2,2"
          #endif
```

I know I can pass #defines to the compiler using
 command line options, but it doesn't seem 
 to work on resource files

my resource file is as follows

```
          #include "myheaders.h"

          VS_VERSION_INFO                       VERSIONINFO
          FILEVERSION                           APP_VERSION
          PRODUCTVERSION                        APP_VERSION
          FILEFLAGSMASK                         VS_FFI_FILEFLAGSMASK
          FILEFLAGS                             VS_FF_PRERELEASE
          FILEOS                                VOS__WINDOWS32
          FILETYPE                              VFT_APP
          FILESUBTYPE                           VFT2_UNKNOWN

          BEGIN
          BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
          BEGIN
          BLOCK "000004b0"
          BEGIN
          VALUE "ProductName",                  APP_TITLE
          VALUE "ProductVersion",               APP_VERSION_STR
          VALUE "FileDescription",              APP_DESCRIPTION
          VALUE "FileVersion",                  APP_VERSION_STR
          VALUE "CompanyName",                  APP_AUTHOR
          VALUE "LegalCopyright",               APP_COPYRIGHT
          VALUE "Comments",                     APP_COMMENTS
          END
          END
          BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
          BEGIN
          VALUE "Translation",                  0x000,0x4b0
          END
          END
```

APP_TITLE expands to the correct string in all source files except in the
resource file, where it just causes a syntax error..

if I define APP_TITLE without the macro conditional everything works well..

Comment: use the `-D` command line switch?

Comment: `#if __OUTPUT__ =="foo.exe"` In this way you will not be able to use the string(`"foo.exe"`).

Comment: I don't think that this could possibly work.  The preprocessor runs independently of the compiler and assembler which again run independently of the linker but only the last of those four will care about the name of the final executable.  But by that time, it will be *way* too late for the preprocessor to make any decision.

Comment: @5gon12eder I know that this is a CodeBlocks question, but in Visual Studio land the IDE has pre-defined macros for things like the target file name, and you could use them in Pre-Build events like the OP wants (but I think that that would be crazy).  However I have no idea if such things exist in CodeBlocks

Comment: @PeterM Apparently I forgot that there are some really strange IDEs out there…  Well, at least there cannot be a *portable* solution since it is perfectly fine to link one and the same object file into two completely different executables.

Comment: As I specified in my answer, he's compiling a *resource.rc* file, not a *source.c* file. Hence, he needs to use the /d option of rc.exe.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Resources get compiled with rc.exe, not the C/C++ compiler.  You need to use the /d option of rc.exe to specify either `/d MYPROJECT` for `/d SIDEPROJECT`

Then in code:

```
      #ifdef MYPROJECT
      #define APP_TITLE                     "my project"
      #define APP_VERSION                    0,0,0,1
      #define APP_VERSION_STR               "0,0,0,1"
      #endif

      #ifdef SIDEPROJECT
      #define APP_TITLE                     "side project"
      #define APP_VERSION                    0,0,2,2
      #define APP_VERSION_STR               "0,0,2,2"
      #endif
```

Comment: Yes - it compiles, but it does not work --- I have a file called resource.rc which also include "myheaders.h" and uses APP_TITLE etc to fill in the fileinformation ,, - and it fails

Comment: It sounds like you are building a Windows project and need to pass the same defines to the resource compiler.  Are you using rc.exe to compile the .rc file?  If so, use the `/d option`.  More details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381055%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: at run time, the argv[0] is a pointer to the string that contains path/executableName  you can use the basename() function to extract the executableName  then use a compile/llink sequence that outputs the desired file name